# state management in vue js with multiple if condition to fetch data using ID

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state-management

I am using vue.js state management for fetching products, state.products is an array[], where my data is stored.
i want to fetch data with ID, i am making condition if state.products is not empty, and i am checking condition in if statement, if already fetched data is match with ID i used as static than return other wise, it'll hit the API to get data. but it has some mistake, please help me to find my mistake

index.js

```
 

    loadProducts({ commit }, id) {
                if (this.state.products.length > 0) {
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < this.state.products.length; i++) {
                        if (this.state.products[i].category_id == 1 && this.state.products[i].category_id == 2) {
                            console.log("RETURN")
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                axios.get('/loadProducts/' + id)
                    .then(({ data }) => {
                        this.state.products = data.items;
                        console.log(this.state.products);
                        commit('set_products', data.items)
                    })
    
            },
```

Products.vue

```
 

    mounted () {
                this.fetchItems();
                this.$store.dispatch("loadProducts",this.category);
            },
            computed:{
                ...mapState([
                    'products'
                ])
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the response and pass the filtered array to the mutation:

```
actions: {
    loadProducts({ commit }, id) {
      axios.get("/loadProducts/" + id).then(data => {
        var filtered_products = data.items.filter(
          x => x.category_id === 1 && x.category_id === 2
        );
        commit("SET_PRODUCTS", filtered_products);
      });
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_PRODUCTS(state, payload) {
      state.products = payload;
    },
  },
```

Depending on your use case you could also use a getter to filter products and then import the getter instead of state.